# How to paint a circle as background in a textView instead of square background?

Tags: android, background, textview

I'm trying to paint a circle as background of a textView dynamically, but instead of that it paints the entire square background

I've tried with a static way that works :
here my code

`circle_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <corners android:radius="4dip" />
    <stroke
        android:width="5dip"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</shape>
```

`list_item.xml`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tag"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="B"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.454" />
```

it works statictly  with:

```
 TextView tv_tag = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_tag);
 tv_tag.setText(itemTag);
```

[image: circle]

but when I try to change the background color with `setBackgroundColor` it doesn't work

```
 TextView tv_tag = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_tag);
 tv_tag.setText(itemTag);
 tv_tag.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D81B60"));
```

[image: square]

Any help will be awesome for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this, hope it will help you.

```
GradientDrawable bg = (GradientDrawable)tv_tag.getBackground();
bg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D81B60"));
```

Comment: change `Color.BLACK` by `Color.parseColor("#D81B60")` works great!

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez .... if it solves your problem then please accept this as an answer.

Comment: @Jack Hossain sure!

Answer (score 1):

`setBackgroundColor` will not use a shape drawable. It will just set color, not your expected shape. So instead use `setBackground` like-

```
tv_tag.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.circlw_drawable))
```

Comment: How can I add the color ?

Comment: I was adding a randon color with a function `colorRandon()` 
 in `tv_tag.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorRandon()));`, but i don't kwon how can I do the same with `setBackground `

Comment: You can also create i.e. 5 drawable background shape. Then randomly choose from those 5 and use it

Answer (score 1):

```
    TextView tv_tag = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_tag);
    tv_tag.setText(itemTag);
    tv_tag.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.circle_drawable));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `setBackgroundColor()` method, we change the background color, but color set to background of textView, the by default background shape of any view in android is rectangle.

To set the particular background shape we can use the drawable.

In your code you changed the background color of textView with cause of rectangular shape of textview.

To change the color of background you need to change color of drawable.

Please try below code to change the color of drawable:

Add this code to your activity

```
TextView tv_tag=findViewById(R.id.tv_tag);
Drawable mDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable);
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED,  PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
tv_tag.setBackground(mDrawable);
```

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You could modify it simply like this

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```